# I want to a send message to a specific consumer in RabbitMQ. Do you have a solution?

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to a send message to a specific consumer in RabbitMQ. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RabbitMQ - Send message to a particular consumer in a queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783240/rabbitmq-send-message-to-a-particular-consumer-in-a-queue)

Comment: or of [Is RabbitMQ capable of “pushing” messages from a queue to a consumer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521854/is-rabbitmq-capable-of-pushing-messages-from-a-queue-to-a-consumer)

Comment: You should make sure to check previous StackOverflow questions. As @ceejayoz has pointed out there are many pointers here to do basic things with many technologies. If there is a more specific issue, please clarify what you are having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

In `RabbitMQ`, you cannot send a message to a specific `consumer`. You maintain a `queue` for the specific `consumer` which listens to that queue. Then, you route the message to the `queue` using a `routing key`. You can use a `exchange` which routes the `specific message` to the `specific queue`.