# RabbitMQ topic exchange, send messages to particular consumer

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

We have the following setup:

RabbitMQ topic exchange with 2 bindings (routing keys) on a queue that connects to 2 load balanced instances of an application.

When we send a message on the topic, it is redirected to 1 of the two consumer instances (round-robin).

In our application, the order of messages may sometimes matter, hence it is a problem when 1 message is processed before the other.

Is there a way to direct the same type of message to a specific consumer?
We use Spring Boot to put the messages on the queue.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35783240/rabbitmq-send-message-to-a-particular-consumer-in-a-queue

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521854/is-rabbitmq-capable-of-pushing-messages-from-a-queue-to-a-consumer

Comment: "Is there a way to direct the same type of message to a specific consumer?" - that's what separate queues are for. If you connect two consumers to the same queue, you're explicitly saying that you _don't_ mind which consumer gets which message.

Comment: @IMSoP Ok we'll work our way around this.